# Missing info.plist file for C++ command line tool application within Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos-high-sierra, info.plist, command-line-tool

I want to create a camera calibration application with opencv for a university course. I have created a command line tool application on macOS High Sierra. Unfortunately it came without an info.plist file. My application crashes with the following error message:

> CameraCalibration[2314:193066] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>   Program ended with exit code: 9

I have already tried adding a info.plist file and setting it in the applications' General tab. I have also added the NSCameraUsageDescription key and string. Unfortunately my application keeps on crashing due to the exact same error.

Comment: I thought so too. But why is my application asking for one?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my previous comment since it was wrong. Have a look at [Apple's Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html). It has a section for single file tools.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can embed an `Info.plist` in your binary by setting `Create Info.plist Section in Binary` and setting a path to your `Info.plist` file in `Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Packaging` (changes marked in bold):

[image: Xcode target Info.plist settings]

Your `Info.plist` might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycorp.myapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>record from the microphone</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>record from the camera</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**N.B**: when running in the debugger in Xcode (11.2.1/Catalina 10.15.1) I still get a  privacy exception, however the plist *is* embedded in the binary. I guess this is an Xcode bug. Dropping an `Info.plist` into the `Products` directory works around this, although you seem to have to re-authorise microphone/camera usage every time the binary is modified.

Comment: Thanks for the Info.plist in Products directory tip!

Comment: That didn't work for me ; i can't read the plist info fwith swift

Comment: This question isn't about reading your own plist - can you start a new question?

Comment: I am seeking a solution to add an Info.plist for an already created executable, i.e. without the use of Xcode. I suspect the `ld` cmd can do that. Any idea how, precisely?
Huh, this q is specifically about use _with_ Xcode. I'll try to find another one.

Comment: the --sectcreate args mentioned here seem to be what you're looking for: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/13795#issuecomment-1021358936